# VBA replace logo in Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little strange question. I used to have few reports worked upon daily.

All these are in Excel and had a logo of the company in all the sheets of each file.

However, now the company name is changed and hence a new logo needs to be replaced in place of the existing. Wanted to check if this replacement can be done with VBA.

I tried with the application.shapes method. But, was confused to proceed further.

Comment: try recording yourself doing it then look at the generated code.

Comment: How many shapes do you have in each sheet? Did you name the Logo the same in all places it appears ?

Comment: Hi Shai... I have one logo... it is pasted in all the sheets of the reports. Each report has multiple sheets varying from 2 to 10 sheets. Thanks

Comment: @Nathan_Sav... I tried recording, but it is having only 2 line of code... When i run it , its not working....

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

```
Sub ChangePicture(strNewPath As String)

Dim oOld As Picture
Dim oNew As Picture

Set oOld = ActiveSheet.Pictures(1)
Set oNew = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strNewPath)

oNew.Left = oOld.Left
oNew.Top = oOld.Top
oNew.Width = oOld.Width
oNew.Height = oOld.Height

oOld.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nathan,Thanks for this wonderful program. Its working fine. However, if there are multiple sheets in the same workbook, do i need to use a for loop?    Also, what if a sheet does not contain the logo?

Comment: Option Explicit
 
Public MyFile As String
Public Stopped As Boolean
 
Sub main()
     Stopped = False
    UserForm1.Show (vbamodless)
         If Stopped Then Exit Sub
     MsgBox MyFile
     Call ChangePicture
    'etc...
 End Sub

Sub ChangePicture()
Dim oOld As Picture
Dim oNew As Picture
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set oOld = ActiveSheet.Pictures(1)
Set oNew = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filepath)
oNew.Left = oOld.Left
oNew.Top = oOld.Top
oNew.Width = oOld.Width
oNew.Height = oOld.Height
oOld.Delete
Next ws
End Sub

Comment: The above code has been updated around the program you gave. I would like to check if a logo exists in each sheet and then replace with new one. But the above code works only for first sheet of the workbook